# Codeforces Round 671 Div 1 C (ultimate wierdness of array)

Tags: algorithm, segment-tree

## Codeforces 671 Div 1 C (ultimate wierdness of array)

> Let vi be b1, b2, b3...bk. Note that our l - r must be cover at least
> k - 1 of this indexes. l must less or equal to b2.

I was able to understand the first part of the solution, but can someone please explain the above statement.

[editorial link](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/44821)

Answer (score 2):

Because if `(l-r)` covers less than `k-1` indexes, then there must be `x`, `y` such that `bx` and `by` is out of range `[l, r]`, and because `i | a[bx], i | a[by]`, then `gcd(a[bx], a[by]) >= i`, which is not right, because you are updating `next` from `i` to `i-1`.

Because `(l-r)` covers at least `k-1` elements of `b1, ..., bk`, so `l` must be less than or equal to `b2`.

Comment: i think i understand what u r saying, but i am still not fully convinced with their editorial, what they are doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

define F(l,r) value indicate A[1：n] Subsequence.

A[1....(l-1),(r+1)....]  to calculate the max gcd(A[i],A[j])

---

Sum = ∑ ∑F(i,j)   (i!=j)